вызов асинхронной функции в __init__ класса
Есть класс MyClass. В нем определяем __init__. Как в __init__ запустить асинхронную функцию? Для усложнения задачи: MyClass запускается тоже из асинхронных функций. ChatGPT предлагает довольно кривые решения.
async def myFunction():
    myClass = MyClass()

async def mySecondFunction():
    pass

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        await mySecondFunction()  # Нерабочий вариант


__init__ вызываете не вы, а интерпретатор. Вызов синхронный, с этим сделать ничего нельзя. Но можно обернуть конструирование:
async def myFunction():
    myClass = await MyClass.make()


async def mySecondFunction():
    pass


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod    
    async def make(cls):
        self = cls()
        await mySecondFunction()
        return self

Наведу красоту. Декоратор async_init оборачивает объявление класса в функцию с тем же именем. Функция асинхронная. Она синхронно вызывает конструктор и асинхронно метод self.post_init(). В вызывающем коде всё выглядит как класс с асинхронным конструктором.
import asyncio


def async_init(cls):

    async def factory(*args, **kwargs):
        self = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        await self.post_init()

    return factory


async def mySecondFunction():
    print('in mySecondFunction')


@async_init
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def post_init(self):
        await mySecondFunction()


async def main():
    myClass = await MyClass()


asyncio.run(main())


Интересный вариант, надо с ним поэкспериментировать. Интерпретатор - это только программа, а инициализирую классы я. Так что это я вызываю.

Волшебные методы, такие как __init__, программист не вызывает непосредственно. По крайней мере не должен в нормальном коде. Метод __init__ вызывается внутри __new__ без await. Вы можете определить __new__, чтобы он делал await __init__(...), но тогда возникнет вопрос как вызывать сам __new__. В конце концов мы придём к статическому методу класса, наподобие make. В прочем, всё можно упрятать под капот, чтобы вернуться к вызову await MyClass(), но внутренности будут страшные.

Тут не вопрос правильности написания программы, а вопрос наличия воли. Я пишу программу, я знаю, что сделать, чтобы она запустилась, я ее запускаю. В данном случае, даже если функция запускается автоматически, все равно процесс запуска инициализирую я.

Не в вашей воле добавить await в библиотечный код перед вызовом __init__. Этот код уже написан. Хорошо что разработчики добавили возможность модификации этого кода, но эта возможность не поможет решить текущую задачу (я повторяюсь).

Хорошо, останемся при своих. Спасибо за код!

Накидаю больше вариантов:
1. Собственный конструктор через метод класса
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls):
        data = await some_async_function()
        return cls(data)

async def main():
    instance = await MyClass.create()

Аналогично можно сделать со статическим методом или отдельной функцией.
2. Самостоятельный вызов функции асинк иницииазации
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    async def initialize(self):
        self.data = await some_async_function()

async def main():
    instance = MyClass()
    await instance.initialize()

3. Отложенная инициализация
Если ожидать инициализации не нужно, можно её вызывать в фоне, при этом уже имея объект:
import asyncio

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        asyncio.create_task(self.initialize())

    async def initialize(self):
        self.data = await some_async_function()

async def main():
    instance = MyClass()

Можно добавить property с проверкой инициализации или отдельный метод на ожидание конца инициализации, если это нужно в каких-то ситуациях.

Третий вариант не срабатывает: import asyncio async def some_async_function(): return 55 class MyClass: def init__(self): self.data = 28 asyncio.create_task(self.initialize()) async def initialize(self): self.data = await some_async_function() async def main(): instance = MyClass() print(instance.data) if __name == "main": asyncio.run(main()) Скорее всего из-за уже запущенного цикла событий –
